# Creating scrapper to send notification from website upon change date

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to write a script to scrape this website and send mail or notification once date changes. [image]

For ex. current date is 7 jan 2022, I want to write script in which once date is change i get notification or mail.
URL : [URL](https://www.statistiques.developpement-durable.gouv.fr/donnees-mensuelles-de-lenergie)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems faced?

Answer (score 1):

Create a script that will run on a daily basis and check if the date is changed. It will also save the current date in a file.

Script will read the file and check with the date given on the site. If they are different then send an email.

Get the date by selenium by `driver.find_element(By.ID,"resume").text` [image]

For selenium, you can deploy to [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/)(free) as a cron job.